# Making an element resizeable dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to dynamically give an element the `jQuery UI Resizable` once it has been added to the dom uaing the following:

```
      insert.click(function(e) {
        var selectedImage = $(this).parent().find('.gallery-item.active');
        var htmlImage = selectedImage.find('img');


        var selectedDiv = $('.zone.selected .drag-image');
        //selectedDiv.clone().append(htmlImage);

        var insertedImage = htmlImage.clone();
        var resized = insertedImage.resizable();
        console.log(selectedDiv);
        console.log(resized);
        resized.appendTo(selectedDiv);

      });

    });
```

What this does, it finds an image that has been clicked on and given the `active` class. when `insert-image` (a href button) is clicked, copy the image and append it to the DOM.

This works fine. The problem comes when trying to give the image the `resizeable`.

When running the above code, the `img` inserted to the DOM has the following HTML;

It doesn't seem to include any of the UI code that displays the resizeable arrows image, i.e

```
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style=""></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style=""></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001;"></div>
```

Is there a way i can add all of the code that makes the element resizeable?

Comment: Try appending `insertedImage` and *then* calling `resizable()`? Not sure it would work, but the element not actually being added to the DOM might cause an issue with placing those other elements.

Comment: That seemed to work a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just re-produced your code and it seems to work fine, check out this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gYdMV/

Updated with click event: http://jsfiddle.net/gYdMV/1/

Code:

```
var insertedImage = $('#htmlImage').clone();
var resized = insertedImage.resizable();
insertedImage.appendTo($('#content'));

<div id="content">
<div id="htmlImage">
    hi
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My code is called within a `click event`. So, it isn't `resizeable` by default.

Comment: @sipher_z That shouldn't change anything with the code in this answer. code running in a click event is no different than it running on window load event or dom ready or at end of body.